# Anime with a girl in a school uniform looking through binoculars, whilst sitting on the shoulders of a boy holding her aloft

Tags: story-identification, anime

Here’s a short clip of the anime: https://vm.tiktok.com/ZMNbhsCVW/?k=1

Answer (score 5):

It is [A Good Librarian Like A Good Shepherd (Episode 8)](https://www.bilibili.tv/TH/video/2043201152)

[image]

Plot

> Kakei goes to library to enjoy reading by himself. He then meets a
> second-year girl named Shirasaki through the efforts of a so-called
> "shepherd" who fulfills people's wishes. Eventually, his boring life
> change.

and [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Good_Librarian_Like_a_Good_Shepherd)

> When Kyōtarō was young, he aspired to read all the magic books in the
> world which were kept in the magic library. To gain access, he
> acquires a bookmark, which is an entry ticket to the magic library,
> and he must show kindness and bring happiness to everyone's hearts.
> Being the sole member of the Library Club, he enjoys the fact that he
> can read peacefully by himself. **After receiving a text from the
> 'shepherd', which reads his fate is going to change, Kyōtarō
> encounters a second-year girl named Tsugumi Shirasaki, whom he saves
> at the train station**.

> The shepherd is well known throughout the school, and is rumored to appear in front of those who are working hard, and **grant wishes**.

> ...Seeing no other options, Kyotaro **uses his Shepherd magic, to
> transport the lights along with Takigawa**, Nagi and himself to
> symposium where Takigawa unknowingly confesses before Mochizuki and
> everyone in there

It is **"urban fantasy"**.